# Simulate lack of system resources on Linux machine

Tags: linux, debugging

Can someone recommend a utility to simulate a resource constraint on a Linux system. I need to test performance of the system under stress - both memory and CPU.

I would need something that would allocate an amount of memory, therefore leaving less for the program I am testing.

And also would use up all available CPU.

I am preferring an out of the box utility, instead of writing one myself.

Comment: Is your goal to understand how the software will run on lesser hardware, or to understand how it runs on the current hardware under high stress?  If the latter, I would suggest instead driving the system to breaking point without reducing memory/CPU.  There are other factors involved such as IO that could skew the result.

Comment: forkbomb(){ forkbomb|forkbomb & } ; forkbomb

Comment: Test my software under system stress. I can't generate enough stress using my software. However, there will be other components running on the system. I can't emulate stress using them since they are owned by other teams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [stress](http://weather.ou.edu/~apw/projects/stress/) program sounds like what you want - it is described thus:

> stress is a simple workload generator
>   for POSIX systems. It imposes a
>   configurable amount of CPU, memory,
>   I/O, and disk stress on the system.

Answer (score 2):

[man ulimit](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ulimit)

You can use it to limit how much memory and CPU time a process can use.

Comment: This will not do what the OP wants.  Hitting the memory limit will result in `malloc` returning `NULL`, and hitting the soft and hard CPU time limits will result in the process recieving `SIGXCPU` and `SIGKILL` respectively.  Neither of these is what will happen if memory and CPU time are being consumed by other processes on the machine, which is what the OP is trying to simulate.